# Intersection of elements of a sigma algebra with a common element.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ a measurable space; $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ a countable algebra, such that $\sigma(\mathcal{B}) = \mathcal{A}$. For $\omega \in \Omega$;
$$A(\omega) = \cap \{A:\, A\in \mathcal{A}, \, \omega \in A\} $$
Show that $A(\omega)  = \cap \{B:\, B\in \mathcal{B}, \, \omega \in B\}$.

I was trying to do this question, the part "$\subseteq$" is easy, since $\{B:\, B\in \mathcal{B}, \, \omega \in B\} \subseteq \{A:\, A\in \mathcal{A}, \, \omega \in A\}$, but I don't know how to prove the "$\supseteq$". I tried a proof by contradiction considering $x\in \cap \{B:\, B\in \mathcal{B}, \, \omega \in B\}\setminus A(\omega)$ and considering the set "$A(x)$", I tried to construct a "good" $\sigma-$algebra since our $\sigma-$algebra is the "smallest" that contains $\mathcal{B}$, but none of my attempts worked well.

So, my question is, how to prove $A(\omega)  \supseteq \cap \{B:\, B\in \mathcal{B}, \, \omega \in B\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\Omega$ such that $\omega\sim\omega'$ if and only if $\omega$ and $\omega'$ lie in exactly the same elements of $\mathcal{B}.$ Note that $A(\omega)$ is simply the equivalence class containing $\omega$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ consist of arbitrary unions of such equivalence classes. Verify that $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{B}$ and that
$$A(\omega) = \cap \{A:\, A\in \mathcal{F}, \, \omega \in A\}.$$

Comment: Oh, thanks for the answer, but why is "_Note that $A(\omega)$ is simply the equivalence class containing $\omega$_" true? Let $x \in A(\omega)$ and $x \neq \omega$, we don't know if there is $B' \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B'$ and $\omega \not\in B'$, I think, so $x$ is not necessarily equivalent to $\omega$, or it is?

Comment: In that case, $\omega\in\Omega\setminus B'$. Since $\mathcal{B}$ is an algebra, we have $\Omega\setminus B'\in\mathcal{B}$. So $\Omega\setminus B'$ is part of the sets one takes the intersection over. But this implies $x\notin A(\omega)$.

Comment: Just one last question, how can the empty set be an element of $\mathcal{F}$? Since $\mathcal{F}$ consist of arbitrary unions of equivalence classes, and none of the equivalence classes is empty, the $\sigma-$algebra shouldn't be $\mathcal{F}\cup \{\varnothing\}$? Thanks again.

Comment: You can take an "empty union." Formally, for any family of sets (set of sets) $\mathcal{S}$, you define $\bigcup\mathcal{S}$ as $\{x\mid x\in S \text{ for some }S\in\mathcal{S}\}$. Then $\bigcup\emptyset=\emptyset$.